# How to get installed Passpoint profiles in android for OS 11,12 and 13

Tags: android, wifi

I tried this:

public List getConfiguredNetworks ()

but this results in a null response, every time even with configured Passpoint network.

```
private fun addPasspointProfile() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val config = PasspointConfiguration()
            config.credential = Credential().apply {
                userCredential = Credential.UserCredential().apply {
                    eapType = 21
                    username = *******
                    password = *******
                    realm = *******
                    nonEapInnerMethod = "PAP"
                }
            }

            config.homeSp = HomeSp().apply {
                fqdn = ***********
                friendlyName = "TESTING_PASSPOINT"
            }

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                val suggestions = ArrayList<WifiNetworkSuggestion>()
                val wifiNetworkSuggestion = WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
                    .setPasspointConfig(config)
                    .setIsHiddenSsid(false)
                    .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true)
                    .build()

                val networkSuggestionList = listOf(wifiNetworkSuggestion)
                wifiManager.removeNetworkSuggestions(networkSuggestionList)
                suggestions.add(wifiNetworkSuggestion)
                val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestions);
                if (status === WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).e("Add Passpoint profile .. Success...in version = %s",
                           Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)
                } else {
                    Timber.tag("PasspointPOC").e("Add Passpoint profile ..Failure...")
                }
            } else {
                wifiManager.addOrUpdatePasspointConfiguration(config)
                Timber.tag("PasspointPOC").e("Success...in version = %s", +Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)
            }
        }
```

Can someone help me out here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same issue, I want to check if a user has previously added my `PasspointConfiguration`. After adding the config I tried querying `wifiManager.networkSuggestions`, but it returns an empty list. Did you ever figure it out?